# SQL- Higher row value is greater than all below rows then return true else false

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
ID  Salary
1   90
2   78
3   68
4   67
5   62
```

Above employee, the query needs to return true because Emp1 salary is greater than Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5, and Emp2 is greater than Emp3 Emp4, Emp5, and go on.

```
ID  Salary
1   90
2   78
3   68
4   97
5   62
```

Above the employee table, the query needs to return false because Emp 3 is lesser than Emp4. It is not in descending order.

Comment: MySQL != Oracle, even though Oracle now owns MySQL, as they do have MANY syntax differences. Still only need ONE TAG for the DB that you are _really using_ using as the previous comment said.

Comment: Please describe the issue you want to solve. In SQL table is not a spreadsheet and rows have no inherent order, so it is not clear how you define "the first" row in a dataset.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT MIN(outcome) AS outcome
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY id
  MEASURES
    CLASSIFIER() AS outcome
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( ^ (FALSE|TRUE)+ $ )
  DEFINE
    FALSE AS PREV(salary) <  salary,
    TRUE  AS PREV(salary) >= salary OR PREV(salary) IS NULL
)
```

or the `LAG` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT MIN(outcome) AS outcome
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN salary <= LAG(salary, 1, salary) OVER (ORDER BY id)
         THEN 'TRUE'
         ELSE 'FALSE'
         END AS outcome
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Salary) As
SELECT 1, 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 78 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 68 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 67 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 62 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | OUTCOME |
> | --- |
> | TRUE |

and, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Salary) As
SELECT 1, 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 78 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 68 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 97 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 62 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | OUTCOME |
> | --- |
> | FALSE |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f83716ed699ba16276e8230e3333b261)*